# Substitute function call syntax inside a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like

```
s = "2+3-5+sqrt(6)+5
```

I have to make it to

```
s = "2+3-5+(6 ** 0.5)+5
```

How can I replace **sqrt(num)** with **(num ** 0.5)** in Python?

Comment: `"2+3-5+sqrt(6)+5".replace("sqrt6", "(6 ** 5)")` wont this do the job?

Comment: @NarenMurali Obviously not, it would need regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for `re.sub`:

```
In [511]: re.sub('sqrt\((\d+)\)', r'(\1 ** 0.5)', text)
Out[511]: '2+3-5+(6 ** 0.5)+5'
```

The relevant regex is `'sqrt\((\d+)\)'`. It'll match a pattern of the form `sqrt(x)`, and will capture the number inside the function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use regular expressions.

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r"sqrt(\([0-9+*/ -]*\))", lambda m:m.group(1)+" ** (0.5)", s)
```

Do not that this will only be able to handle it if sqrt(expression) has no further brackets in the expression.
Hope it helps.

EDIT: Ninja'd